# $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus C_r(0)$, $r>0$ connected for n>1

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus C_r(0)$, $r>0$ is connected for n>1 where $C_r(0)$ denotes the ball around $0$ with radius $r$.

What's the easiest way to show this? Directly or via path connected?

I thought about working with the following:

For $n>2$ the $n-1$ sphere $S^{n-1}$ is connected and
$R^n\setminus C_r(0) \longrightarrow\ S^{n-1}: x \mapsto\ \frac{x}{||x||},$
is continuous and surjective.

Is it correct to say that therefore $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus C_r(0)$ has to be connected? Because usually the lemma goes the other way: a continuous image of a connected set is connected.

Or are there other, simpler ways to prove ths?

Comment: What is **the** circle around $0$ with redius $r$?

Comment: $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $d(x,0) \le r$ where $d$ is the distance provided by an arbitrary norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: That is a ball, not a circle.

Comment: Draw a picture for $n=2$. You still think it's connected?

Comment: Ah, I see, you mean **ball**. You should edit the question!

Answer (score 1):

Let $n \ge 1$ and define ${E_n}^{*} = \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{\vec 0\}$. It is not difficult to show that the punctured Euclidean space ${E_n}^{*}$ is connected,

Define the unit sphere as $S_{n-1} = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^n \, | \; \; \lVert v \rVert = 1 \}$. The mapping $v \mapsto\ \frac{v}{\lVert v \rVert}$ is a continuous surjection of ${E_n}^{*}$ onto $S_{n-1}$, so the unit sphere is connected.

Recall that if $D$ is a [clopen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set) of a topological space $X$ that contains a point $x$ belonging to a connected subspace $G$ of $X$, then $G \subset D$. This is used implicitly several times in what follows.

Exercise: If $B_r(0)$ is a closed ball about the zero vector $\vec 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, show that

$\tag 1 M = \mathbb{R}^n \setminus B_r(0)$

is connected.

**Sketch**

The sphere $G$ of radius $r + 1$ is a connected subspace of $M$.

$M$ is the union of lines with each one intersecting $G$ in exactly one point (c.f. the polar representation of vectors). Any clopen of $M$ must contain all lines (and line segments/rays) emanating from any point belonging to it.

Let $D$ be any nonempty clopen of $M$ with $\vec v \in M$. By using a scalar factor on $\vec v$, it must be true that $D$ contains a point belonging to $G$. Then it must be true that $G \subset D$. Then it must be true that $M \subset D$. Then it must be true that there is no nontrivial decomposition of $M$ into two clopens. So $M$ is connected.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to prove that it is path connected. It is not hard to see that if $p$ and $q$ belong to your set, then you can always find a third point $s$ such that both the line segment going from $p$ to $s$ and the line segment going from $s$ to $q$ are subsets of your set.

Comment: So let's say $p$ and $q$ belong to my set and $s$ is the line from $p$ to $q$. Then I define a vector $v$ which is orthogonal to $s$ and divide it by $||v||$ so that $v$ has norm $1$. And then I thought about the path from $p$ to $p+rv$, from $p+rv$ to $q+rv$ and from $q+rv$ to $q$ on the direct way. Is this correct? Maybe I need $(r+\epsilon)v$ where $\epsilon >0$ or $r+2v$?

Comment: @user564662 This depends upon where $p$ and $q$ are. For instance, in most cases you can go from $p$ to $q$ in a straight line. But, yes, something like that will work.

Comment: is $r+2v$ enough for every case?

Comment: What does that mean? SInce $v$ is a vector and $r$ is a number, what is $r+2v$?

Comment: Typo. I meant: Usually I can go from $p$ to $q$ in one straight line. But in the worst case: is $p \rightarrow p+rv \rightarrow q+rv \rightarrow q$ enough? Or do I need $p \rightarrow p+2rv \rightarrow q+2rv \rightarrow q$? $v$ is orthogonal to $s$ and has norm $1$

Comment: @user564662 Actually, in a limit case you will need to take a number greater than $2r$ instead of $2r$.

Comment: Why? I cant visualize it. What is the worst case in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus C_r(0)$ for example?

Comment: Suppose that $r=1$, $p=(2,-1)$, $q=(-2,-1)$, and that $v=(0,1)$. Then you'll need to take a numer greater than $2r(=2)$.